# CSS Background Color for :before / :after independent of parent

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I have a series of CSS rules to add FontAwesome icons before/after links for PDFs, phone numbers, email addresses, etc.

Additionally, I have a global hover rule for links, which makes the background color of all link elements yellow.

```css
.main a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main a[href^="tel"]:before {
  content: '\f879';
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main a[href^"tel"]:hover::before {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Phone: <a href="tel:131313">131313</a></p>
  <p><a href="/test.html">Normal link - no icon</a></p>
</div>
```

My problem is that I don't want the yellow hover color to apply to the icons.

If I set the hover color on the pseudo-elements to a specific color (e.g., not transparent), everything is okay. But these links can appear anywhere (cards, accordions, etc.), which may have different background colors, so I'd rather not have to define every possible instance.

Comment: I can't think of a way to achieve your desired result as `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are displayed inline by default which prevents their background colors from appearing when the main element has its own. If you `display: block;` to your `:before` you will see that its background color remains transparent but it is no longer inline. Are you open to using JavaScript to achieve your desired result?

Comment: @GeorgeSun thanks for the explanation - that makes a lot of sense. Regarding JavaScript, my preference is to avoid it for something like this. However if there was a simple way to implement, without any significant load on the page, I'd consider it.

Comment: There is a simple way to do it with jQuery. If this interests you I can write a solution for it.

Comment: @GeorgeSun. Yes please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution using jQuery to wrap with `span` all anchors that have attribute `href` starting with "tel". I don't have FontAwesome imported here so your icon does not display correctly, but you can see that your desired highlighting works even when the anchor is surrounded by paragraph text.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href^="tel"]').html('<span>' + $('a[href^="tel"]').html() + '</span>');
});
```

```css
.main a:before {
  content: '\f879A';
}
.main a span:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <p>Hello, <a href="tel:131313">131313</a>!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks the most likely option at this stage - however I would need to add the <span> tags in on all body links (not just those with icons) - as I want all body links to have the color background on hover. Worried how this might impact page load speeds

Comment: One way to find out. Hard reload your page with and without the JavaScript and compare the load times reported by the web inspector.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much difference. Have modified the the jQuery to: 
$('.main a').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
});

Answer (score 0):

You can give `position: absolute` styling to your pseudo-element. This will seperate it from its parent. Try the following:

```
.main a[href^="tel"] {
  content: '\f879';
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.main a[href^="tel"]:before {
  content: '\f879';
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Adjust the margin according to your liking!

Comment: This solution works only if no contents precede the anchor in the paragraph element. If contents precede the anchor, the `:before` pseudo-element displays to the left of the paragraph.

Comment: I don't follow you. He just wanted to seperate `:before` from `a`, and that's what I helped him do. He might have to adjust the pseudo-element's position sure, but it will work regardless.

Comment: Apply your styling to `<p>Hello, <a href="tel:131313">131313</a>!</p>` and you will see that the icon displays to the left of the entire paragraph, not just to the left of the anchor.

Comment: Yes, obviously,when you apply the stylings to the `<p>` tag it will display to the left of the `<p>` tag, it only makes sense.  That's why I applied them to the `<a>` tag. So what are you saying here? I've never even talked about the paragraph, my styling rules were clearly directed to the `<a>` element. You can stop trying to prove me wrong so you can push your own solution please.

Comment: Loizos, my point is that your solution is great when the anchor is alone in the paragraph, but if any contents are added prior to the anchor, as I have done in my previous comment (`<p>Hello, <a href="tel:131313">131313</a>!</p>`), it does not behave as desired. I'd appreciate if you'd refrain from being argumentative; I'm only trying to be constructive with your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Loizos. This would work in certain circumstances, but as @GeorgeSun pointed out, as soon as other content is added to the paragraph the formatting breaks. I've updated my initial question to show more realistic use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shifted gradient but you will need to update the value based on your case as it will depend on the size of the icon:

```css
.main a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(yellow 0 0) 10px no-repeat;
}

.main a[href^="tel"]:before {
  content: '\f879';
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main a[href^"tel"]:hover::before {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p><a href="tel:131313">131313</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a pure CSS solution. Works great if all my links have icons - but this is not the case. On standard links, the gradient is still shifted. See updated question. Can't wait for the :has selector to be adopted.